# A program that replaces all s1's with s2 in a string

Tags: c

I found this program that replaces all s1's with s2 in a string and i don't understant the sequence
  int i = strstr(s, s1) - s ?

```
enter code here
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

char *my_replace(char *s, char *s1, char *s2)
{

    char *aux = (char *) malloc((sizeof(s) - sizeof(s1)) + sizeof(s2) + 1);
    int i = strstr(s, s1) - s, j = strlen(s1);
    strncpy(aux, s, i);
    strcat(aux, s2);
    strncat(aux, (s + i + j), (strlen(s) - i - j));
    return aux;
 }


 int main()
 {
    char *s, *s1, *s2;
    s = (char*)malloc(10);
    s1 = (char*)malloc(10);
    s2 = (char*)malloc(10);
    char *aux;
    scanf("%s%s%s", s, s1, s2);
    aux = my_replace(s, s1, s2);
    printf("%s\n", aux);
    return 0;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

> .. and i don't understant the sequence: `int i = strstr(s, s1) - s`

Well, it gives you the offset in `s` where `s1` was found.

Example:

```
char* s = "abcdef";
char* s1 = "cd";
printf("%d\n", strstr(s, s1) - s);
```

Will give the result `2`

It's because `strstr` returns a pointer to the beginning of the located substring and then by substracting the start on the string (pointer arithmetic) you get the offset between them.

You can see it like this:

```
 abcdr
 ^ ^
 | | 
 | strstr(s, s1)
 |
 s
```